# QtCreator Поиск регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qtcreator

Есть много файлов, пробую поиском найти строки подобные такому:

```
void Call() const
```

Такой регуляркой

```
void Call\(\) const([^\s]+)
```

Дабы потом заменить на подобное:

```
void Call() const override
```

Но моей регуляркой находятся уже переименованные функции в такие:

```
void Call() const override
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваше регулярное выражение означает:

1. Текст `void Call() const`
2. НЕ пробельный символ минимум один раз

То есть оно соответствует тексту к примеру:

```
void Call() constantin
void Call() const()
и.т.п.
```

Вероятнее всего - это не то, что Вам нужно.
Скорее всего Вас удовлетворит выражение, которое ищет текст справа от которого пробельные символы до конца строки. То есть в этой строке больше ничего нет.

```
void Call\(\) const\s*?(?=\n|$)
```

Если не так - конкретизируйте вопрос приведя больше примеров и описания что надо найти.

Comment: Спасибо, но ваша регулярка ищет всё, например:  

     void Call() const override  

Его искать не нужно, а нужно просто найти такие функции:     
      void Call() const (без слова override)

Comment: Поэтому я и написал, что Вам нужно уточнить вопрос. Его суть слабо понятна.